# VM down : Failed to read /vm/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/domains: has this domain already been cleaned up?

Tags: xen, xcp-ng

I'm having a problem with my xcp-ng server, and I'm using the xcp center 20.04.01 on Linux xcp-ng 4.19.0+1. I didn't done anything like update before the issue occurred, everything was working fine since months.

Here's what I can still do:

- Connect to the server via xcp center and SSH
- View all servers and snapshots
- Start or stop a virtual machine

However, I'm facing some issues which are:

- The 'Performance' tab is not showing any data.
- The console for running VMs is not showing anything.
- The started VMs are not responding to IP.
- VM tab in greyed out

I tried to :

- analyze the logs and search for the errors without success
- xe-toolstack-restart
- restart VMs
- restart whole server

Can anyone provide steps to solve these problems?

cat /var/log/xensource.log | grep err

```
Aug 31 18:24:59 xcp-ng xenopsd-xc: [error||19 |Async.VM.start R:ffffffffffff|xenops] Failed to read /vm/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/domains: has this domain already been cleaned up?
Aug 31 18:24:59 xcp-ng xenopsd-xc: [ info||19 |Async.VM.start R:ffffffffffff|xenops] VM = xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; Hardware Assisted Paging will be enabled. Use platform/hap=(true|false) to override
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1249 HTTPS x.x.x.x->|Async.VM.start R:ffffffffffff|sql] Duplicate key in set or map: table task; field other_config; ref OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-qqqq-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy; key debug_info:cancel_points_seen
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] event.from D:dddddddddddd failed with exception Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ])
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] Raised Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ])
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 1/13 xapi Raised at file ocaml/xapi/xapi_event.ml, line 434
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 2/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/xapi_event.ml, line 606
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 3/13 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 24
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 4/13 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 35
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 5/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/xapi_event.ml, line 587
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 6/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/xapi_event.ml, line 698
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 7/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/rbac.ml, line 223
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 8/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/rbac.ml, line 231
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 9/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/server_helpers.ml, line 103
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 10/13 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/server_helpers.ml, line 121
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 11/13 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 24
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 12/13 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 35
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 13/13 xapi Called from file lib/backtrace.ml, line 177
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1247 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace]
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace] Raised Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ])
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace] 1/4 xapi Raised at file ocaml/xapi-client/client.ml, line 7
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace] 2/4 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi-client/client.ml, line 19
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace] 3/4 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi-client/client.ml, line 3956
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace] 4/4 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/xapi_xenops.ml, line 3071
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||backtrace]
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] session_check D:eeeeeeeeeeee failed with exception Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ])
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] Raised Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ])
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 1/6 xapi Raised at file ocaml/xapi/session_check.ml, line 63
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 2/6 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/server_helpers.ml, line 100
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 3/6 xapi Called from file ocaml/xapi/server_helpers.ml, line 121
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 4/6 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 24
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 5/6 xapi Called from file lib/xapi-stdext-pervasives/pervasiveext.ml, line 35
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace] 6/6 xapi Called from file lib/backtrace.ml, line 177
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||1353 /var/lib/xcp/xapi||backtrace]
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [debug||511 ||helpers] Helpers.call_api_functions failed to logout: Server_error(SESSION_INVALID, [ OpaqueRef:yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyy ]) (ignoring)
Aug 31 18:25:00 xcp-ng xapi: [error||511 ||xenops] events_from_xapi: missing from the cache: [ yyyyyyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxx-zzzzzzzzzzzz ]
[18:25 xcp-ng log]#
```

**[update]**
In dmesg, I found :

```
[    4.217516] Call Trace:
[    4.217518]  <IRQ>
[    4.217521]  dump_stack+0x5a/0x73
[    4.217524]  report_bad_irq+0x30/0xc0
[    4.217525]  note_interrupt+0x208/0x260
[    4.217526]  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x51/0x70
[    4.217528]  handle_irq_event+0x36/0x60
[    4.217528]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x78/0x130
[    4.217529]  generic_handle_irq+0x24/0x30
[    4.217532]  evtchn_fifo_handle_events+0x180/0x1a0
[    4.217534]  __xen_evtchn_do_upcall+0x5f/0xb0
[    4.217534]  xen_evtchn_do_upcall+0x27/0x50
[    4.217536]  xen_do_hypervisor_callback+0x29/0x40
[    4.217537]  </IRQ>
[    4.217538] RIP: e030:xen_hypercall_sched_op+0xa/0x20
[    4.217539] Code: 51 41 53 b8 1c 00 00 00 0f 05 41 5b 59 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 51 41 53 b8 1d 00 00 00 0f 05 <41> 5b 59 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
[    4.217540] RSP: e02b:ffffffff82003e58 EFLAGS: 00000246
[    4.217541] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffff82011740 RCX: ffffffff810013aa
[    4.217541] RDX: ffffffff8203d250 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000001
[    4.217542] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000008 R09: 00000000fc9e909a
[    4.217542] R10: 0000000000007ff0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[    4.217542] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffff82011740 R15: ffffffff82011740
[    4.217543]  ? xen_hypercall_sched_op+0xa/0x20
[    4.217545]  ? xen_safe_halt+0xc/0x20
[    4.217546]  ? default_idle+0x1a/0x140
[    4.217547]  ? do_idle+0x1ea/0x260
[    4.217548]  ? cpu_startup_entry+0x6f/0x80
[    4.217550]  ? start_kernel+0x558/0x578
[    4.217551]  ? set_init_arg+0x55/0x55
[    4.217552]  ? xen_start_kernel+0x599/0x5a3
[    4.217552] handlers:
[    4.217581] [<00000000d7be1930>] tis_int_handler
[    4.217655] Disabling IRQ #45
```

It seems that it could be linked to BSD vm. My ethernet controller is ntel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T

Comment: It seems to be linked with one vm containing a FreeBSD image. Copying this image on another freshly installed XCP even without running the vm make the hypervisor crash